# The Android Emulator is not working well

Tags: java, android, eclipse, testing, android-emulator

I am new in Eclipse Android I have made a sample calculator but when I wanted to test it in the emulator it didn't worked fine

```
`[2014-06-17 01:19:23 - SampleCalculator] ------------------------------
[2014-06-17 01:19:23 - SampleCalculator] Android Launch!
[2014-06-17 01:19:23 - SampleCalculator] adb is running normally.
[2014-06-17 01:19:23 - SampleCalculator] Performing com.zain.sampleCalculator.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-06-17 01:19:24 - SampleCalculator] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'Test_Nexus'
[2014-06-17 01:19:24 - SampleCalculator] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Test_Nexus'
[2014-06-17 01:20:11 - SampleCalculator] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2014-06-17 01:20:11 - SampleCalculator] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2014-06-17 01:23:30 - SampleCalculator] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-06-17 01:23:30 - SampleCalculator] Uploading SampleCalculator.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-06-17 01:23:32 - SampleCalculator] Installing SampleCalculator.apk...
[2014-06-17 01:25:44 - SampleCalculator] Failed to install SampleCalculator.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2014-06-17 01:25:44 - SampleCalculator] (null)
[2014-06-17 01:25:44 - SampleCalculator] Launch canceled!
[2014-06-17 09:27:56 - SDK Manager] Created AVD '16GB_Nexus' based on Android 4.4.2, ARM (armeabi-v7a) processor,
[2014-06-17 09:27:56 - SDK Manager] with the following hardware config:
[2014-06-17 09:27:56 - SDK Manager] disk.dataPartition.size=200M
[2014-06-17 09:27:56 - SDK Manager] hw.accelerometer=yes
[2014-06-17 09:27:56 - SDK Manager] hw.audioInput=yes
[2014-06-17 09:27:56 - SDK Manager] hw.battery=yes
[2014-06-17 09:27:56 - SDK Manager] hw.camera.back=none
[2014-06-17 09:27:56 - SDK Manager] hw.camera.front=none
[2014-06-17 09:27:56 - SDK Manager] hw.dPad=no
[2014-06-17 09:27:56 - SDK Manager] hw.device.hash2=MD5:6930e145748b87e87d3f40cabd140a41
[2014-06-17 09:27:56 - SDK Manager] hw.device.manufacturer=Google
[2014-06-17 09:27:56 - SDK Manager] hw.device.name=Nexus 4
[2014-06-17 09:27:56 - SDK Manager] hw.gps=yes
[2014-06-17 09:27:56 - SDK Manager] hw.keyboard=yes
[2014-06-17 09:27:56 - SDK Manager] hw.lcd.density=320
[2014-06-17 09:27:56 - SDK Manager] hw.mainKeys=no
[2014-06-17 09:27:56 - SDK Manager] hw.ramSize=1907
[2014-06-17 09:27:56 - SDK Manager] hw.sdCard=yes
[2014-06-17 09:27:56 - SDK Manager] hw.sensors.orientation=yes
[2014-06-17 09:27:56 - SDK Manager] hw.sensors.proximity=yes
[2014-06-17 09:27:56 - SDK Manager] hw.trackBall=no
[2014-06-17 09:27:56 - SDK Manager] skin.dynamic=no
[2014-06-17 09:27:56 - SDK Manager] vm.heapSize=64
[2014-06-17 09:28:16 - SDK Manager] Deleting file C:\Users\HP\.android\avd\Test_Nexus.ini
[2014-06-17 09:28:16 - SDK Manager] Deleting folder C:\Users\HP\.android\avd\Test_Nexus.avd
[2014-06-17 09:28:16 - SDK Manager] AVD 'Test_Nexus' deleted.
[2014-06-17 09:29:01 - SampleCalculator] ------------------------------
[2014-06-17 09:29:01 - SampleCalculator] Android Launch!
[2014-06-17 09:29:01 - SampleCalculator] adb is running normally.
[2014-06-17 09:29:01 - SampleCalculator] Performing com.zain.sampleCalculator.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-06-17 09:29:01 - SampleCalculator] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD '16GB_Nexus'
[2014-06-17 09:29:01 - SampleCalculator] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device '16GB_Nexus'
[2014-06-17 09:29:46 - SampleCalculator] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2014-06-17 09:29:46 - SampleCalculator] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2014-06-17 09:34:22 - SampleCalculator] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-06-17 09:34:22 - SampleCalculator] Uploading SampleCalculator.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-06-17 09:34:24 - SampleCalculator] Installing SampleCalculator.apk...
[2014-06-17 09:36:34 - SampleCalculator] Failed to install SampleCalculator.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2014-06-17 09:36:34 - SampleCalculator] (null)
[2014-06-17 09:36:35 - SampleCalculator] Launch canceled!
[2014-06-17 09:42:58 - SampleCalculator] ------------------------------
[2014-06-17 09:42:58 - SampleCalculator] Android Launch!
[2014-06-17 09:42:58 - SampleCalculator] adb is running normally.
[2014-06-17 09:42:58 - SampleCalculator] Performing com.zain.sampleCalculator.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-06-17 09:42:58 - SampleCalculator] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD '16GB_Nexus'
[2014-06-17 09:42:58 - SampleCalculator] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device '16GB_Nexus'
[2014-06-17 09:43:18 - SampleCalculator] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2014-06-17 09:43:18 - SampleCalculator] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2014-06-17 09:46:04 - SampleCalculator] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-06-17 09:46:04 - SampleCalculator] Uploading SampleCalculator.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-06-17 09:46:06 - SampleCalculator] Installing SampleCalculator.apk...
[2014-06-17 09:48:15 - SampleCalculator] Success!
[2014-06-17 09:48:15 - SampleCalculator] Starting activity com.zain.sampleCalculator.MainActivity on device emulator-5554
[2014-06-17 09:48:21 - SampleCalculator] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.zain.sampleCalculator/.MainActivity }
[2014-06-17 09:55:56 - SDK Manager] SD Card already present with same size, was not changed.
[2014-06-17 09:55:56 - SDK Manager] Updated AVD '16GB_Nexus' based on Android 4.4.2, ARM (armeabi-v7a) processor,
[2014-06-17 09:55:56 - SDK Manager] with the following hardware config:
[2014-06-17 09:55:56 - SDK Manager] disk.dataPartition.size=200M
[2014-06-17 09:55:56 - SDK Manager] hw.accelerometer=yes
[2014-06-17 09:55:56 - SDK Manager] hw.audioInput=yes
[2014-06-17 09:55:56 - SDK Manager] hw.battery=yes
[2014-06-17 09:55:56 - SDK Manager] hw.camera.back=none
[2014-06-17 09:55:56 - SDK Manager] hw.camera.front=none
[2014-06-17 09:55:56 - SDK Manager] hw.dPad=no
[2014-06-17 09:55:56 - SDK Manager] hw.device.hash2=MD5:6930e145748b87e87d3f40cabd140a41
[2014-06-17 09:55:56 - SDK Manager] hw.device.manufacturer=Google
[2014-06-17 09:55:56 - SDK Manager] hw.device.name=Nexus 4
[2014-06-17 09:55:56 - SDK Manager] hw.gps=yes
[2014-06-17 09:55:56 - SDK Manager] hw.keyboard=yes
[2014-06-17 09:55:56 - SDK Manager] hw.lcd.density=320
[2014-06-17 09:55:56 - SDK Manager] hw.mainKeys=no
[2014-06-17 09:55:56 - SDK Manager] hw.ramSize=16384
[2014-06-17 09:55:56 - SDK Manager] hw.sdCard=yes
[2014-06-17 09:55:56 - SDK Manager] hw.sensors.orientation=yes
[2014-06-17 09:55:56 - SDK Manager] hw.sensors.proximity=yes
[2014-06-17 09:55:56 - SDK Manager] hw.trackBall=no
[2014-06-17 09:55:56 - SDK Manager] skin.dynamic=no
[2014-06-17 09:55:56 - SDK Manager] vm.heapSize=64
[2014-06-17 09:56:21 - SampleCalculator] ------------------------------
[2014-06-17 09:56:21 - SampleCalculator] Android Launch!
[2014-06-17 09:56:21 - SampleCalculator] adb is running normally.
[2014-06-17 09:56:21 - SampleCalculator] Performing com.zain.sampleCalculator.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-06-17 09:56:21 - SampleCalculator] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD '16GB_Nexus'
[2014-06-17 09:56:21 - SampleCalculator] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device '16GB_Nexus'
[2014-06-17 09:56:38 - SampleCalculator] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2014-06-17 09:56:38 - SampleCalculator] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2014-06-17 09:59:26 - SampleCalculator] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-06-17 09:59:26 - SampleCalculator] Uploading SampleCalculator.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-06-17 09:59:28 - SampleCalculator] Installing SampleCalculator.apk...
[2014-06-17 10:01:39 - SampleCalculator] Failed to install SampleCalculator.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2014-06-17 10:01:39 - SampleCalculator] (null)
[2014-06-17 10:01:39 - SampleCalculator] Launch canceled!
[2014-06-17 10:11:28 - SampleCalculator] ------------------------------
[2014-06-17 10:11:28 - SampleCalculator] Android Launch!
[2014-06-17 10:11:28 - SampleCalculator] adb is running normally.
[2014-06-17 10:11:28 - SampleCalculator] Performing com.zain.sampleCalculator.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-06-17 10:11:28 - SampleCalculator] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD '16GB_Nexus'
[2014-06-17 10:11:28 - SampleCalculator] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device '16GB_Nexus'
[2014-06-17 10:11:49 - SampleCalculator] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2014-06-17 10:11:49 - SampleCalculator] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2014-06-17 10:14:44 - SampleCalculator] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-06-17 10:14:44 - SampleCalculator] Uploading SampleCalculator.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-06-17 10:14:46 - SampleCalculator] Installing SampleCalculator.apk...
[2014-06-17 10:16:54 - SampleCalculator] Success!
[2014-06-17 10:16:54 - SampleCalculator] Starting activity com.zain.sampleCalculator.MainActivity on device emulator-5554
[2014-06-17 10:17:02 - SampleCalculator] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.zain.sampleCalculator/.MainActivity }
[2014-06-17 10:17:03 - SampleCalculator] ------------------------------
[2014-06-17 10:17:03 - SampleCalculator] Android Launch!
[2014-06-17 10:17:03 - SampleCalculator] adb is running normally.
[2014-06-17 10:17:03 - SampleCalculator] Performing com.zain.sampleCalculator.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-06-17 10:17:03 - SampleCalculator] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD '16GB_Nexus'
[2014-06-17 10:17:04 - SampleCalculator] ------------------------------
[2014-06-17 10:17:04 - SampleCalculator] Android Launch!
[2014-06-17 10:17:04 - SampleCalculator] adb is running normally.
[2014-06-17 10:17:04 - SampleCalculator] Performing com.zain.sampleCalculator.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-06-17 10:17:04 - SampleCalculator] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD '16GB_Nexus'
[2014-06-17 10:17:05 - SampleCalculator] ------------------------------
[2014-06-17 10:17:05 - SampleCalculator] Android Launch!
[2014-06-17 10:17:05 - SampleCalculator] adb is running normally.
[2014-06-17 10:17:05 - SampleCalculator] Performing com.zain.sampleCalculator.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-06-17 10:17:05 - SampleCalculator] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD '16GB_Nexus'
[2014-06-17 10:17:06 - SampleCalculator] ------------------------------
[2014-06-17 10:17:06 - SampleCalculator] Android Launch!
[2014-06-17 10:17:06 - SampleCalculator] adb is running normally.
[2014-06-17 10:17:06 - SampleCalculator] Performing com.zain.sampleCalculator.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-06-17 10:17:06 - SampleCalculator] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD '16GB_Nexus'
[2014-06-17 10:17:07 - SampleCalculator] ------------------------------
[2014-06-17 10:17:07 - SampleCalculator] Android Launch!
[2014-06-17 10:17:07 - SampleCalculator] adb is running normally.
[2014-06-17 10:17:07 - SampleCalculator] Performing com.zain.sampleCalculator.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-06-17 10:17:07 - SampleCalculator] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD '16GB_Nexus'
[2014-06-17 10:17:13 - SampleCalculator] Uploading SampleCalculator.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-06-17 10:17:16 - SampleCalculator] Installing SampleCalculator.apk...
[2014-06-17 10:17:23 - SampleCalculator] Uploading SampleCalculator.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-06-17 10:17:26 - SampleCalculator] Installing SampleCalculator.apk...
[2014-06-17 10:17:33 - SampleCalculator] Uploading SampleCalculator.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-06-17 10:17:36 - SampleCalculator] Installing SampleCalculator.apk...
[2014-06-17 10:17:43 - SampleCalculator] Uploading SampleCalculator.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-06-17 10:17:47 - SampleCalculator] Installing SampleCalculator.apk...
[2014-06-17 10:17:54 - SampleCalculator] Uploading SampleCalculator.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-06-17 10:17:57 - SampleCalculator] Installing SampleCalculator.apk...
[2014-06-17 10:18:34 - SampleCalculator] Success!
[2014-06-17 10:18:34 - SampleCalculator] Starting activity com.zain.sampleCalculator.MainActivity on device emulator-5554
[2014-06-17 10:18:44 - SampleCalculator] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.zain.sampleCalculator/.MainActivity }
[2014-06-17 10:18:55 - SampleCalculator] Installation failed due to invalid URI!
[2014-06-17 10:18:55 - SampleCalculator] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2014-06-17 10:18:56 - SampleCalculator] Launch canceled!
[2014-06-17 10:18:57 - SampleCalculator] Installation failed due to invalid URI!
[2014-06-17 10:18:57 - SampleCalculator] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2014-06-17 10:18:58 - SampleCalculator] Launch canceled!
[2014-06-17 10:18:59 - SampleCalculator] Installation failed due to invalid URI!
[2014-06-17 10:18:59 - SampleCalculator] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2014-06-17 10:18:59 - SampleCalculator] Launch canceled!
[2014-06-17 10:19:00 - SampleCalculator] Installation failed due to invalid URI!
[2014-06-17 10:19:00 - SampleCalculator] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2014-06-17 10:19:00 - SampleCalculator] Launch canceled!`
```

**I tried to lunch it more than once and everytime I got a different result one of these:**
1- The application (Calculator) opened normally but there is a window which is saying "Process system isn't responding. Do you want to close it? Wait/Ok" and sometimes the screen give like a red box around the whole emulator screen.
2- I just got the Home Page sometimes with the same warning "Process system isn't responding. Do you want to close it? Wait/Ok" and sometimes the screen give like a red box around the whole emulator screen. but the difference here that the whole Calculator app doesn't run.

**I did few steps and I thought it might work but it didn't worked perfectly what I did that:** 
 - I increased the RAM and SD to 16GB.
 - I put the ADB Connection time-out(ms) which is in the DDMS from 5000 which is by default to 10000.

Sorry for making this Question that long but I really need your help, and I am sure that some other users faced this problem before.

Comment: Have you tried restarting eclipse?

Comment: _Thanks Ryan_ I just did that now after reading your comment, still the red box is showing but the application run normally. So I guess there is no solution for this red box. isn't it?

Comment: now I have opened the emulator after fixing some problems in the design and stuff but the same problem showed which is:the Home Page only with the warning "Process system isn't responding. Do you want to close it? Wait/Ok" and the red box around the whole emulator screen and the whole Calculator app doesn't run.
So I guess restarting is not the best solution or we should restart every single time which will take so long.

Answer (score 1):

16GB is a huge amount of memory for the emulator. try to use something less than 750MB. I usually use 512Mb for most applications. that could be a reason for this error.

Also Please make sure the TARGET ABI you choose for the emulator should match with your targetSDKversion specified on the AndroidManifest file. There can be number of reasons why this error occurs. Please share the AVD config for any further investigation into this.

Answer (score 0):

This error can point to so many different things, and there is many different fixes. To sum those I've gathered:

Problems with Eclipse: Clean project, rebuild project, restart eclipse.

Invalid characters: Remove any special characters in Eclipse project name. Use only [a-z] and [0-9] not even [ ] (whitespace)

Error in included jar: Try without jar and see if it runs, if does fix somehow.

Errors in manifest package setup: Right click in eclipse on project -> Android tools -> Rename application package (rename to something similar, you can always rename back).
Problems with device: Remove app from device and re install again.

Comment: Thanks Sandeep, well the problems with Eclipse I have tried all these and still the same problem
About the invalid characters I don't think I have any because I checked it but I will again.
the last two (Error in included jar and Errors in manifest package setup) I didn't tried them I will check them..
Thanks again :)